# What's the difference Object.call() and Object.__proto__.call()?

Tags: javascript, object, call

Object doesn't have it's own method call, so it takes it from **proto**, but why then the results are different ?

```js
// Look at results in your browser's console

console.log(
  Object.call(null,2), // Number {2}
  Object.__proto__.call(null,2), // undefined

  Object.call(null,''), // String {""}
  Object.__proto__.call(null,'') // undefined
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.call` is a reference to `Function.prototype.call` (because `Object.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`):

```js
console.log(Object.call === Function.prototype.call);
console.log(Object.__proto__.call === Function.prototype.call);
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype);
```

`Object` is a constructor function (eg, `new Object(...)` gives you an Object). Invoking `Object.call` results in a call to `Function.prototype.call` with a calling context of `Object`, which `Function.prototype.call` uses to figure out which function needs to be called.

So

```
Object.call(null,2)
```

is basically the same thing as

```
Object(2);
```

which gives you a `number` inside an object wrapper.

In contrast, with `Object.__proto__.call`, you're calling `Function.prototype.call` with a calling context of `Object.__proto__`. But `Object.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`. `Function.prototype`, [per the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object):

> accepts any arguments and returns undefined when invoked.

```js
console.log(Function.prototype());
```

So, when `.call` is called with it, no matter what, it'll just return `undefined` (but it won't throw an error or anything, even though you might think it *should* - invoking `Function.prototype` doesn't really make any sense).

The following expressions are all doing the exact same thing:

```
Object.__proto__.call(null,2) // undefined
Function.prototype.call(null,2) // undefined
Function.prototype(2) // undefined
```